# Render a PlotlyDisplay object on Dash UI python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to render a graph on my Dash UI. I created the graph initially using plotly on Jupyter Notebook.

What I want to do is render the same graph on my Dash UI. The code I am trying is:

```
 html.Div([
            new_data.iplot(subplots=True, subplot_titles=True, legend=False)
        ]),
```

I get an error stating:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'PlotlyDisplay' is not JSON serializable
```

Is there anyway I could do this? I'm a newbie with Dash so any help I could get will be great!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `dcc.Graph( ... )` instead of `iplot( ... )`. Here's an example from the documentation: https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started#dash-app-layout

Comment: I am aware of the dcc.Graph(..) property, however, I want to display the same graph which I built using iplot() method. Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Ah well, you might be able to extract the JSON out of the `iplot()` call and pass that to `dcc.Graph()` but you'll definitely need to use `dcc.Graph()`